# Android: LocalBroadcastReceiver does not work

Tags: android, service, local, broadcast, receiver

I have a Service, this Services run a Thread which run a AsyncTask and override the onProgressUpdate method. In this method I send a message to my localbroadcast receiver.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("BookDownloadService");

                    // You can also include some extra data.
                    intent.putExtra("bookID", book.bookID);
                    intent.putExtra("maxValue",  update[1]);
                    intent.putExtra("currentValue",  update[0]);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And in my Activity I want to get the data.

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver( new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int bookId = intent.getIntExtra("bookID", 1);
            int maxValue = intent.getIntExtra("maxValue", 10);
            int currentValue = intent.getIntExtra("currentValue", 0);
            boolean isFinish = intent.getBooleanExtra("isFinish", false);
            Log.d("Receiver Buch " + bookId, currentValue + " von " + maxValue + " finish: " + isFinish);
        }
    }, new IntentFilter("BookDownloadService"));
```

but nothing happens. no log messages or errors.

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html, section **Threading rules**

Comment: all my other code inside it work.

Comment: Replace the `AsyncTask` with a `Thread` (or, use an `IntentService`, depending upon the nature of the service). You do not need an `AsyncTask` in this case, as `LocalBroadcastManager` already delivers its messages on the main application thread. Just call `sendBroadcast()` from the thread. Beyond that, add logging or breakpoints to ensure that the two code segments that you list above are actually ever executed. For example, `onProgressUpdate()` on an `AsyncTask` is only called if you call `publishProgress()`.

Comment: i need the async task to download files. the asynctask works fine but i want to inform the UI in different activitys about the progress with the localbroadcast.

Answer (score 0):

you need to register/unregister the receiver...

```
(onPause)
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

(onResume)
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, <your intentFilter>);
```

Comment: i don't see that. d'Oh...now i do.

Comment: What if I need to do this from Application context?